# React Inside Page Navigation & State Stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am building a react app that should have inside navigation, so I need to keep track of all state. I am thinking to create a state stack and push previous state into it when state changes. I believe doing so can allow me to generate previous page vice verse. How can I do that using life cycle. My try is below. However, I am also confused because I believe I can do this using react router but I do not want url changes though. What is the most elegant way to accomplish this task? Thanks for any help in advance.

```
class ExampleCode extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state={
      state1: null,
      state2: null,
      state3: null,
      stateStack: []
    }
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.setState({
      stateStack: [this.state, ...this.state.stateStack]
   })
  } 
}
```